# Pl/SQL Function syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I can't wrap my head around functions to do with pl/SQL i have code which is supposed to check room capacity but I think I've declared a variable wrong somewhere. Honestly can't see what the problem is.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function RoomCapacity
( name_in IN varchar2 )
RETURN varchar2
IS
R_value number(6);
RLevel varchar2(20);

cursor c1 is
  SELECT room_capacity
  FROM ROOMS
  WHERE room_id = name_in;

BEGIN

open c1;
fetch c1 into R_value;
close c1;

IF R_value <= 10 THEN
  RLevel := 'Low capacity';

ELSIF R_value > 10 and R_value <= 18 THEN
  RLevel := 'Avg capacity';

ELSIF R_value > 18 and R_value <= 30 THEN
  RLevel := 'Moderate capacity room';

ELSE
  RLevel := 'High capacity room';

END IF;

RETURN RLevel;

END;

ROOM_ID
BUILDING_PREFIX
ROOM_FLOOR
ROOM_NUMBER
ROOM_TYPE
ROOM_CAPACITY
ROOM_EQUIPMENT
```

The table ROOMS; is listed above.

Comment: So.... what error are you getting? Because the code looks reasonable - assuming that the client is passing in a name_in that correctly matches to a room_id. Oh, and if the room has a room_capactiy between 19 and 30 then your text string will blow up your varchar2(20) RLevel parameter ("Moderate capacity room" has 23 characters!).

Comment: Does this line `WHERE room_id = name_in` right one ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception or error, post the line it occurred on and the details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any error.
Moreover, I tried your code and it worked like a charm, 
see this fiddle: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ae48/1

---

However, you can simplify your function using CASE expressions, just:

```
   RETURN
   CASE WHEN R_value <= 10 THEN 'Low capacity'
        WHEN R_value > 10 AND R_value <= 18 THEN 'Avg capacity'
        WHEN R_value > 18 AND R_value <= 30 THEN  'Moderate capacity room'
        ELSE 'High capacity room'
   END;
```

Comment: Your test cases didn't include the ones that blow up trying to put 'Moderate capacity room' into RLevel varchar2(20);...... ;-)

Comment: @Michael, thank you for pointing that - please post this as an answer, because  this is a real reason of the issue ('Moderate capacity room' does not fit in varchar(20)`)

Comment: Done - glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good with one exception, your variable defintion of

```
RLevel varchar2(20);
```

and:

```
ELSIF R_value > 18 and R_value <= 30 THEN
  RLevel := 'Moderate capacity room';
```

That string is 23 characters long and will blow up the rLevel variable if you input a room with a capacity in that range.